# SQL UPDATE base on COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

- product-table with fields (id, category_id)
- category-table with fields (id, num_of_products)

The product table contains multiple products in different categories.
And I know how to count product in each categories using

```
SELECT category_id, COUNT(product.id) as count FROM product GROUP BY category_id
```

But how do I update category.num_of_product using a single sql query with the result of the SELECT .... ?
I have tried but can not figure out the proper syntax !!

```
UPDATE c
SET num_of_products = count
FROM category c
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT category_id as id, COUNT(product.id) as count FROM product GROUP BY category_id) d ON c.id = d.id
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Stop and just **don't**. Drop the column `num_of_products`. Data should be kept redundancy free to avoid the possibilities of inconsistencies. So writing a sum over one table into another isn't a good thing to do. If you need the sum, you can always query it and get the **right** result. For convenience you can create a view that stores such a query so you don't have to repeat it every time.

Comment: My tables contain +5.000.000 product, +5.000 categories and it takes several seconds to get the count(s) even using indexes. 
So I need to have fast access to these count.

Today I'm doing it in two step, but want to run a single sql query once a day. after the  product table are updated.

Comment: I have doubts about these figures but OK. If you can live with the inconsistencies you may get...

Comment: How frequent does the product being added? Will you have new product every minute/hour/day?

Comment: The product-table are update once a day .. and it is okay if the count is not 100% up to date as they are only for visual purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
UPDATE category c 
JOIN (SELECT category_id, COUNT(id) cnt 
        FROM product GROUP BY category_id) p
ON c.id=p.category_id
SET c.num_of_products=cnt;
```

If you want to do `UPDATE` with `JOIN`, you must do the `JOIN` first then followed with `SET`. If there are conditions then you need to add `WHERE` after the `SET`. For example, let's say there are some category you don't want to update then probably:

```
UPDATE category c 
JOIN (SELECT category_id, COUNT(id) cnt 
        FROM product GROUP BY category_id) p
ON c.id=p.category_id
SET c.num_of_products=cnt
WHERE c.id NOT IN (1,2);
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f674896807fa4927231b9d48566a38ce)